# ruamel.yaml: how do I add a new element at the top level, and inside other elements

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

`ruamel.yaml` docs are sparse, and I haven't found the responses I needed here.

Contents of `my_file.yaml`:

```
desc: "blahblahblah"
```

Q1: How do I (programmatically) add "size" as an element **at the same level** as "desc" (i.e. at the TOP level of the tree)

Q2: How do I (programmatically) add subelements **n-times deeper**

The resulting file should look something like this:

```
desc: 
    - "blahblahblah"
    - "desc_trans":
        - "Chinese": 
          - "Mandarin": "blahblahblah"
          - "Uyghur": "blahblahblah"
        - "Spanish": "blahblahblah"
size: "40k"
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], please read the [tour] it has some valuable information on how the site works. "Thanks" and other things that don't contribute to the clarity of a question/problem, should be left out. And yes the documentation of `ruamel.yaml` is lacking, due to its author slacking.

Answer (score 2):

`ruamel.yaml` docs are sparse, but what you are trying to do is mostly
on the Python level.  You don't change YAML, you load YAML from a file
and parse it into a data structure, change that data structure (using
Python, as `ruamel.yaml` is a Python package) and then dump the data
structure back to YAML.

First of all: you cannot get exactly what you want, as your indentation
of sequences is inconsistent. The value for `desc` has an indent of six,
with the offset of the block sequence indicator (`-`) within that
being four. The value for `"desc_trans"` has an indent of four with an
offset of two, and that for `"Chinese"` has the minimal indent of
two. `ruamel.yaml` has only one pair of sequence indent and offset
values applied to all (block) sequences.

There are a few tricky things you are trying to achieve:

- loading a scalar value for the key `desc` and magically translating
  it into a sequence (with the old scalar value being the first
  element).  The code should of course make this change only when
  necessary.
- having a mix of plain scalars combined with scalars with superfluous
  double quotes. If I see it correctly, any scalar string that is not a
  key of the root-level mapping should be double quoted. You can achieve
  that programmatically, but in the example I'll do that by hand.

Assuming Python3:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString as dq

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(Path('my_file.yaml'))

assert isinstance(data, dict)  # check that the root-level is a dictionary like object 
data['size'] = dq('40k')

if not isinstance(data['desc'], list):
    data['desc'] = [data['desc']]  # change the non-list into a list
l = data['desc']
# make the desc_trans dict first, cannot use dict(desc_trans=[dict(Chinese=[Mandarin=....
desc_trans = []
l.append({dq('desc_trans'): desc_trans})
Chinese = {dq('Chinese'): [{dq('Mandarin'): dq('blahblahblah')}]}
Spanish = {dq('Spanish'): dq('blahblahblah')}
desc_trans.append(Chinese)
desc_trans.append(Spanish)
# the next line also could be simplified using `desc_trans.append()`
data['desc'][1]['desc_trans'][0]['Chinese'].append({dq('Uygur'): dq('blahblahblah')})

# if you want to write to a file use: out = Path('output.yaml')
out = sys.stdout
yaml.dump(data, out)
```

which gives:

```
desc:
  - "blahblahblah"
  - "desc_trans":
      - "Chinese":
          - "Mandarin": "blahblahblah"
          - "Uygur": "blahblahblah"
      - "Spanish": "blahblahblah"
size: "40k"
```

In general I recommend assigning a deep element to a variable and then
appending or assigning new keys to that.

As `ruamel.yaml` actually loads the mappings in an ordered dictionary subclas,
it is not really necessary to have these sequences of single key-value
pair mappings, that you have as value for `"dest_trans"` and for
`"Chinese"`. Leaving out the lists simplifies the code, and the subclass has
an `.insert()` method to give the necessary control over the key ordering.